# Is there a firewall that shows alerts whenever an app is trying to connect somewhere?

Tags: firewall

Are there any firewall software apps for Ubuntu that work like ZoneAlarm or Comodo Firewall, which pop up an alert every time a program tries to connect to the Internet, write any files, or hooks and gives you the ability to accept or deny the action?

Comment: Keep in mind that a program with admin privileges on Windows can get around those restrictions...

Comment: I know, but I just like the security of knowing what my apps are up to. I see a lot of rules type firewalls for Linux in general, but nothing on the action by action basis like ZoneAlarm or Comodo.

Comment: Have you tried `gufw` to see if it will pop up messages for the `ufw` firewall?  `sudo apt-get install gufw`

Comment: @Terrance AFAIK those messages go straight and silently into the log files only, there's no popup etc.

Comment: @ByteCommander I know there used to be.  I guess they got rid of that in newer versions.  Thank you!  =)